# how to exclude SFML joystick in c++?

Tags: c++, sfml

when debugging SFML (v2.5.1) in visual studio it's keep logging

> Failed to set DirectInput device axis mode: 1

I findout that this message is from the joystick([from its source code](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Window/Win32/JoystickImpl.cpp))
and i'm linking with dynamic library. Is there any way to exclude the joystick (or any way to get rid of the annoying logging?)

Comment: You can always edit it out of the source and recompile the library.

Comment: So, If you're getting the message, you're using `sf::JoystickImpl` (`JoystickImpl::openDInput` method, in fact). But I guess this is not intentional, because you want to get rid of it. Maybe you are using it unintentonally?